# Can not start up service Gerrit on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gerrit

In my case, I tried to install Gerrit code review in ubuntu 16.04. In that time, i have found one problem with enable service Gerrit using command line

**sudo systemctl enable gerrit**

and executed this above command, then I got error message bellow

**gerrit.service is not a native service, redirecting to systemd-sysv-install
Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable gerrit**

How to fix this problem?

Comment: That isn't an error in itself, it's just a warning that tells you that *gerrit.service* isn't really a systemd service so it's reverting to using sysv instead - Gerrit should still be installed to statr on bootup.

Comment: Could you guide me how to fix it? because i have less experience.

Comment: Have you verified that you've actually got a problem? Does gerrit start when you run `sudo systemctl start gerrit`? If not, you have a different issue, if it does, reboot the server and see if it starts on startup